# Does 'multiport' make a difference in terms of efficiency?

Tags: linux, iptables

Can any one can say definitively that using the `--multiport` extension with iptables rules:

1. Is faster than creating a rule per port?
2. Is slower than creating a rule per port?
3. Makes no difference?

If I had to guess, I would think #1 is most likely, but recognize there must be a chance of #2 or #3 as well.  The [www.iptables.info description of multiport matching](http://www.iptables.info/en/iptables-matches.html#MULTIPORTMATCH) doesn't say anything one way or the other.

The only thing I could find searching the web [is this](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-989892-start-0.html), which implies #2 but is anecdotal, and -- to be prejudicial -- it's easy to be suspicious of gamers and [gentoo users](https://fun.irq.dk/funroll-loops.org/) ;)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is definitely 1.

Let's say you have some rules like this :

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
```

Three times in a row, you will check if the input interface is eth0, and if the L4 protocol is TCP.

With multiport, you check it only once.